# Raise Brightness When Maximizing Terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome, process, window-manager, brightness

I'm looking to raise the brightness when I maximize or foreground the Terminal window which has Vim running. I would like to reset the brightness to normal when I minimize or background that process as well.

I usually need more brightness when working with the black background of Vim than the white background of Chrome so I'd like it to happen automatically.

I use this to programatically decrease the brightness:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Can I somehow hook into the minimize/maximize event of a GUI window and run the above as a script if the window is Terminal with Vim running?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible . behave %@ focus getwindowgeometry |
while read x id && read x && read x; do
  eval "$(xprop -notype -id "$id" \
            8s '=$0\n' WM_CLASS \
            32a '="$0+"\n' _NET_WM_STATE)"
  [ "$WM_CLASS" = gnome-terminal ] &&
    [ "$_NET_WM_STATE" = "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" ]
  rc=$?
  if [ "$rc" != "$last_rc" ]; then
    if [ "$rc" -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "set high brightness"
    else
      echo "set low brightness"
    fi
    last_rc=$rc
  fi
done
```

Replace the `echo ...` with the actual command to set the brightness.

The idea is to use `xdotool` to get notified when the window focus changes. Then, we use `xprop` on the window id reported by `xdotool` to see if the window that currently has the focus is `gnome-terminal` and is maximised.

However, it doesn't work for windows that have connected after `xdotool` has started.

A more robust method could be to just check the current active window in a loop:

```
while :; do
  # wait for a focus event:
  sh -c 'exec xdotool search --onlyvisible . behave %@ focus exec kill "$$"' 2> /dev/null

  id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
  eval "$(xprop -notype -id "$id" \
            8s '=$0\n' WM_CLASS \
            32a '="$0+"\n' _NET_WM_STATE)"
  [ "$WM_CLASS" = gnome-terminal ] &&
    [ "$_NET_WM_STATE" = "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" ]
  rc=$?
  if [ "$rc" != "$last_rc" ]; then
    if [ "$rc" -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "set high brightness"
    else
      echo "set low brightness"
    fi
    last_rc=$rc
  fi
done
```

You can find out more details through the [xdotool man page](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).

Comment: can you explain how to use this? I'm getting this: "xdotool: Unknown command: getwindowgeometry"

Comment: @slm, you need `xdotool 2.20110530` or newer for the `getwindowgeometry` command.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! In both examples I'm getting this error: `line 7: WM_CLASS:: command not found`. Here's my [xprop output](https://gist.github.com/mhluska/5712314) if it helps.

Comment: @MarosHluska, what do you see if you replace `eval` with `echo` above or if you run that code with `sh -x`? What version of `xdotool` do you have?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas if I replace `eval` with `echo` I get a lot of repeated output like this: 

`_NET_WM_STATE="_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ, _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED"
WM_CLASS="gnome-terminal"`. There is a newline before `WM_CLASS=...`. My `xdotool` version is `2.20110530.1`